# Why is string declared 'globally' different than declared 'locally'?

Tags: c++, string

**Problem : Given a string S, of length N that is indexed from 0 to N-1 , print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as space-separated strings on a single line i.e. if String is Hacker Output should be Hce akr.**
*I wrote this code...*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    string str;
      string evenStr;
      string oddStr;
    for(int i=1; i<=T; i++)
    { 
      cin>>str;
      for(int j=0;j<str.size();j++)
        (j%2==0) ? (evenStr+=str[j]) : (oddStr+=str[j]);

      cout<<evenStr<<" "<<oddStr<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**For input T=2 and two strings "Hacker" "Rank"...this code Outputs "Hce akr"
"HceRn akrak"**
**But this code prints the correct result...Why?**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T;
    cin>>T;

    for(int i=1; i<=T; i++)
    { string str;
      string evenStr;
      string oddStr;
      cin>>str;
      for(int j=0;j<str.size();j++)
        (j%2==0) ? (evenStr+=str[j]) : (oddStr+=str[j]);

      cout<<evenStr<<" "<<oddStr<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**For input T=2 and two strings "Hacker" "Rank"... Correct Output: "Hce akr" "
Rn ak"**

Comment: Where's your globally declared string?

Comment: In the first version you need to explicitly 'reset' `evenStr` and `oddStr` at the top of the outer loop -- otherwise you just keep appending characters to them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the string every time otherwise you will repeat the work in old string.

```
 //locally declared
for (...)
{
  string evenstr;
  //work
}
```

Other wise

```
// out of loop declared.
for (...)
{
  evenstr="";
    //work
}
```